# Handle spark DataFrame structure

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's suppose that we have the following two tables

```
+---------+--------+
|AUTHOR_ID| NAME   |     
+---------+--------+
|  102    |Camus   |
|  103    |Hugo    |

+---------+-------- +------------
|AUTHOR_ID| BOOK_ID + BOOK_NAME  |     
+---------+-------- + -----------|
|  1      |Camus    | Etranger
|  1      |Hugo     | Mesirable  |
```

I want to join the two table in order to get a **DataFrame** with the following Schema

```
root
 |-- AUTHORID: integer
 |-- NAME: string 
 |-- BOOK_LIST: array 
 |    |-- BOOK_ID: integer 
 |    |-- BOOK_NAME: string
```

I'm using **pyspark**, Thanks in advance

Comment: What issues are you having using `join` functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple join + group by should do the job:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = (df_authors.join(df_books, on=["AUTHOR_ID"], how="left")
          .groupBy("AUTHOR_ID", "NAME")
          .agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("BOOK_ID", "BOOK_NAME")))
          )
```

In the aggregation we use `collect_list` to create the array of structs.

Comment: what if we want to list of books ordered by BOOK_ID ? adding `orderBy` before the `groupBy` seems not working!